# Verwendung von "es" im Satz "lasse mich es wissen"

Tags: personal-pronoun

Wenn ich jemandem "let me know" sage, soll ich dann "es" im Satz verwenden? Im Internet sehe ich, dass die beiden Varianten verwendet werden. Aber welche ist richtig, oder was ist der Unterschied in der Bedeutung? Z.B. wie sollen diese beiden Varianten ins Englische übersetzt werden?

Comment: "dass die beiden Varianten verwendet werden" - kannst du Beispiele zeigen, wo die Variante ohne "es" verwendet wird?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=lasse+mich+wissen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let me know

is a shortened phrase where the *it* (or something else) is omitted:

> Let me know about it. Let me know how it works out. Let me know what he says.

In German, you can’t omit the *es*.

> Lass es mich wissen. Lass mich wissen, wie es gelaufen ist. Lass mich wissen, was er sagt.

Comment: Ich habe den Verdacht, "Let me know about it." klingt auf Englisch irgendwie besser als "Let me know it."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Danke, ergänzt.